# Using strtok() together with fgets() causes a segfault, but pointers should be correct

Tags: c, file-io, fgets, strtok

I'm pretty new to C and thought I'd learn a bit more. I'm trying to write some code that reads a pre-existing text file and formats and writes it to disk. While it compiles, I get a segfault every time when I'm not sure I should be getting one. I went over most of the man pages and couldn't find anything that sticks out.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   FILE *file = fopen("listing.txt","r"), *output;

   char *fvar;
   char *svar;
   char delim[] = ",";
   int num;
   char ch;
   char line[66];
   int listnum = 0;

   if(file == NULL){
        printf("Cannot open file.\n");
        exit(1);
   }

   output = fopen("report.txt","w");

   fprintf(output, "%s", "First Name     Last Name     Number ");
   fprintf(output, "%s", "-------------------------------------");

   while(fgets(line, 66, file) != NULL){
       ch = line[0];
       if((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z')){
           fvar = strtok(line,delim);
           svar = strtok(NULL,delim);
           listnum++;
       }
       else {
            num = atoi(line);
       }
       fprintf(output, "%s", fvar);
       fprintf(output, "%15s", svar);
       fprintf(output, "%30d", num);
       fprintf(output, "%56s", "\n");
   }
   fclose(file); /* done reading from the input file */
   fclose(output); /* done writing the the output file */
   return 0;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is read a line of the text file. If the line contains info in the manner "string,string" then tokenize both of those and store them in fvar and svar respectively. If it is a numeric string, use atoi() to get the value and store it in num.

For some reason this causes a segfault, though it compiles fine. I'm pretty sure that the problem is in the lines `fvar = strtok(temp,delim);` and `svar = strtok(NULL,delim);`, but I don't know how to amend it. Note : the same behaviour occurs if I use `fvar = strtok(line,delim);`.

*Edit*: Fixed, thanks @Chris Dodd. As per my own volition, I will go fetch a first grade text book and study my alphabet again.

Comment: temp = line; - This doesn't work as you're simply setting two pointers to be equal to each other. What you really want to do is a memcpy() or strcpy() from line to temp. This isn't why your program is segfaulting though. Finally, I think the line 'num = atoi(line);' should be 'num = atoi(ch);', you want only to convert a single ASCII character, not the complete line.

Comment: @DaV: No, `temp` is declared as an array, not a pointer; it won't even compile.

Comment: You're describing a run-time failure, but the code you showed us won't even compile.  `temp = line;` is illegal because you can't assign to an array.  `listnumnum++;` is illegal because you never declared `listnumnum` (it's `listnum`).  Please copy-and-paste your exact code.  (Consistent indentation would also be helpful.)

Comment: @Keith Thompson: But line is also declared as a simple array. Should it be an array of pointers? Edit: Sorry about the listnumnum. I'm not sure how that happened. I was probably typing something extra, but the rest of the code is the same. And yes, the `temp = line;` causes it to be unable to compile, but without it - it does. I'll remove those lines for clarity.

Comment: Yes you're right Keith, my mistake. Think I need to go to bed :-)

Comment: @user991710: No.  If you want `temp` to hold a copy of `line`, you can do this: `strcpy(temp, line);`

Comment: I tried that as well, to no effect. However, from what I have read I should be able to manipulate `line` directly and use it a an argument for `strtok()`, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely problem is that your first input line doesn't begin with a lower case letter, so you never call strtok in the first place, and never assign to either svar or fvar, but you still pass those (uninitialized) values to printf, which then gives a segfault...

Try using a debugger to single-step through the code to see where it actually goes.

Comment: Hah! I can't believe I was stumbling around because of something so simple. Indeed, the pre-populated files have uppercase letters. Thank you for the catch.

Comment: Didn't see your edit there (and mine's over 5 mins) : I would've used one but I'm doing this on a linux terminal. Perhaps I should opt for an IDE sooner rather than later.

Comment: No need for an IDE -- gdb works just fine from a terminal.  Or use emacs, which gives you windowing and an IDE even over a terminal

Answer (score 0):

strtok can return NULL.   If you ignore that possibility, access violations are easy to cause.   always check the return status of a function you call.

```
fvar = strtok(temp, delim); 
if (fvar != NULL) 
{
    printf("%s\n", fvar);
    svar = strtok(NULL, delim);
    if (svar != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", svar);
    }
    else
    {
        /* illegal to access contents of svar */
    } 
 } 
 else 
 {
     /* illegal to access contents of fvar */ 
 }
```

/*
    unrelated to the question, you may find the include file ctype.h useful, as it provides
    a family of functions of the form.... toupper, isletter, isdigit and things like that
*/

Comment: True, thanks for the tip. However, the file is pre-populated in the manner I described and I call strtok() only twice within each iteration if the data is non-numeric. That should never cause `strtok()` to return `NULL`, should it?

Comment: :)   if it will never return NULL, then you should check for it as above, and print an error message that tells you that the impossible has happened.   I see impossible things happen all the time :)